# Persisting Data to the Database from a WCF Servicer

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wcf, entity-framework

I have a WCF application in C# .NET 4.0. I made all my entity classes and can query a sample from the WCF. The sample is just hard coded values.

Now I am ready to persist these in the database. I am lost on how to approach this though. I plan to create tables for each entity class I created, but what is the best way to add the persistent data layer to my existing WCF application. Is Entity Framework a good choice for this? Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest is to use entity framework *code first*. It prevents you from re-creating the model/database by hand. Just set it up so that your current entity classes are mapped to the entity framework and it will automatically create the database for you.

If you google **entity framework code first**, i'm sure u cant miss it.